# AJAX POST Request JQuery, PHP working individually but not together

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a couple of simple input fields and a button to submit it. I want to submit the values without loading or refreshing the page. So i am using JQuery AJAX Post request. I tried my PHP Mysql Database script seperately and it works fine. But the problem is AJAX returns success but my DB is not updated.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "routesave.php?one=" + rt + "&two=" + st + "&three" + lat + "&four" + lon + "&five" + eta,
  success: function(response) {
      alert('yay ajax is done.');

    } //close succss params
});
```

and PHP

```
<?php
    $route = $_GET['one'];
    $stop  = $_GET['two'];
    $lat   = $_GET['three'];
    $lon   = $_GET['four'];
    $eta   = $_GET['five'];
    sql    = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'digitrack' );

    if ($sql->connect_error) { 
        die("connection failed:". $sql->connect_error);
    }

    $query = $sql->query("insert into routes (route, stop, lat, lon, eta) values ('$route', '$stop', '$lat', '$lon' , $eta) ");

    if ($query!=TRUE) {
       echo "error".$sql->error;
    }
?>
```

Comment: use `type: 'GET` in your ajax

Comment: Note that `sql` is missing a dollarsign, and you seem to be vulnerable to injection and should be using prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: Also note that in your get variables you forgot a few `=` signs.

Comment: I corrected these two errors but still have the same problem. Kindly help

Comment: `type: 'POST',` Need to be `type: 'GET',` Because you are sending data through query-string(`GET` request) via `ajax` ***And***
`url: "routesave.php?one=" + rt + "&two=" + st + "&three" + lat + "&four" + lon + "&five" + eta,` Need to be `url: "routesave.php?one=" + rt + "&two=" + st + "&three=" + lat + "&four=" + lon + "&five=" + eta, //=missing` ***And***
`sql    = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'digitrack' );` Need to be
`$sql    = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'digitrack' );//$ missing`

Note:- try to read `prepared statements` and use them to prevent from `SQLInjection` .